# Golang create custom validator that executes method of an interface

Tags: validation, go, go-playground

I am trying to create my own validator for gin, but I want it to be "generic", so let's say, I want to have an interface IsValid

```
type IsValid interface {
    IsValid() bool
}
```

, and make some structs to have binding:"IsValid" in some fields that implement that interface.

But I don't know how to write my custom validator to get the field, cast it to the IsValid interface, and then execute the isValid method.

I am using the go-playground validator package: https://github.com/go-playground/validator

```
if v, ok := binding.Validator.Engine().(*validator.Validate); ok {
    // registering validation for isValid
    v.RegisterValidation("isValid", func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
        isValidField := // TODO do something to cast it to that interface
        return isValidField.IsValid()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FieldLevel`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9#FieldLevel) type has this method:

```golang
// returns current field for validation
Field() reflect.Value
```

[`reflect.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value) has [this method](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Interface):

```golang
func (v Value) Interface() (i any)
```

> Interface returns v's current value as an interface{}. It is equivalent to:
>
> `var i interface{} = (v's underlying value)`
>
> It panics if the Value was obtained by accessing unexported struct fields.

You can use a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to utilize an `interface{}` / `any` value as a more specific interface like this:

```golang
var i interface{} = something
var x = i.(MyInterface)
```

This will panic if the value `i` doesn't implement `MyInterface`. To check for that case, the alternate form can be used:

```golang
var x, ok = i.(MyInterface)
if ok {
    // use x
} else {
    // type conversion failed
}
```

Putting it together, your code would be something like this:

```golang
isValidField, ok := fl.Field().Interface().(IsValid)
```